# Why did the Piasezcner's students give his writings the title Aish Kodesh?

Tags: jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, holocaust-shoah

I have a copy of Polen's *The holy fire* but I don't currently have access to the Hebrew or English versions of *Aish Kodesh*. Is it known why the Piasezcner's students in Israel gave this title to his writings?

Answer (score 4):

A little while ago, I found the answer in a 2019 Tablet article by Shaul Magid, "A new history of holy fire" (https://www.tabletmag.com/sections/belief/articles/a-new-history-of-holy-fire). Magid writes:

The text was published in 1960 under the name *Esh Kodesh*. This was the only printed edition until Reiser’s volume appeared in 2017. The name *Esh Kodesh* was decided upon by the editors and publishers. In the Introduction to the 1960 edition we read, “We have called this book *Esh Kodesh* as a remembrance to all the holy ones who perished in fire … and the name also hints to our master, his father, and his son [who also perished in the Holocaust].” That is, our master died in a holy fire and the names of his father and son were Elimelekh Shapira, or Esh.